# Service worker "install" event downloads files again which should already exist in browser cache

Tags: caching, browser-cache, service-worker, service-worker-events

Before adding a service worker and caching the app-shell, the outgoing requests for files related to the web-page (e.g. main.css, app.js, shims.js..) were cached by the browser. Thereby, any further request for these files returned the cached version (and if max-age expired, these requests are validated with the Etag), that includes requests with a timestamp as well. (This behaviour is still like the same during normal visits of the page.)

Now the web-page (PWA) requests the content for the first time. After the content is received, the service worker install event starts fetching the specified files in the background:

```
var urlsToCache = [
  "/",
  "/css/main.css",
  "/js/app.js",
  "/js/shims.js",
  "/assets/playstore.png",
  "/assets/logo_amcs_small.png",
  "/assets/appstore.png",
  "/assets/i18n/en.json",
  "/assets/i18n/de.json",
  "/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0"
];
```

Some of them are taken from the browser cache (disk/memory cache), but some are downloaded again (de.json, en.json, app.js, shims.js, main.css), see the attacehd image. All these URIs contain a timestamp when the request is executed from the webpage, but are still returned from the browser cache on further request.

Why this is different when fetching these files in the "install" event of the service worker?

[image: network requests on first load of the PWA - service worker installs without anything in the cache]

Btw, I'm trying to reduce the overall network requests, therefore it's not very nice to download these files again..